# HTML -Espaçamento entre tds

Tags: html, css, table

Existe alguma forma de dar espaçamento entre `<td>` como na figura abaixo?

OBS: Com espaçamento apenas na direita da `<td>`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode usar margin em cada uma. Exemplo, use no seu css: td{margin-right:10px;}

Comment: @TiagoP.C já tentei, não pega margin em td's

Comment: Então com padding, como diz a resposta do Pedro, abaixo.

Comment: padding é espaçamento interno, no meu caso quero dar espaçamento externo.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, há uma forma utilizando o `border-collpse` e `border-spacing` no **CSS**:

```css
table td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
table{
  border-collapse: separate; 
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1
        </td>
        <td>
          Coluna 2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1
        </td>
        <td>
          Coluna 2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Danilo, tinha feito com o cellspacing, mas vi que ele não é suportado pelo HTML5.

Comment: Sim ele nao é suportado, foi editar a minha resposta

Answer (score 2):

Consegui o efeito que você precisa colocando uma classe na td da coluna em questão e usando um css personalizado pra ela:

```css
td { background: gray; padding:10px }
.tdEspaco { display: table; float:left; margin-right:10px }
table { border-spacing: 5px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='tdEspaco'>1</td>
    <td >2</td>
    <td >3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='tdEspaco'>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='tdEspaco'>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Há uma maneira mais fácil do que utilizar o padding, o padding é espaçamento interno

Comment: O padding que eu coloquei não influencia na resposta. Foi só questão de estética.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar a propriedade `css` [border-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp) na sua `table`.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 15px 10px;
}
table>tbody>tr>td {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Coluna 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Coluna 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: padding é espaçamento interno, no meu caso quero dar espaçamento externo.

Comment: Tente isso, nem sempre padding dá espaço interno.

Comment: Não deu cara, já tentei.

Comment: @BrendolL. Eu que não li direito sua pergunta. =/  Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Consegui fazer com  border-collapse: separate; e  border-spacing: 10px 3px; mais desse jeito nao consigo tira a margin da direita =/

Comment: @BrendolL. confere as alterações que fiz.

Comment: margin-right: 0 não resolve, para tirar a margin da direita? Olhe minha resposta.

Answer (score -4):

Consegui mais simples impossivel

```
border-right: solid 10px #fff;
border-bottom: solid 3px #fff;
```

Comment: Mais aí você não está dando espaço. Você esta deixando a borda mais espessa na cor branca.

Comment: Isso me parece gambiarra. É melhor você aprender do jeito certo do que fazer esse tipo de coisa.